# Java NIO nonblocking: how to refuse incoming connections?

Tags: java, connection, nio, nonblocking

I'm trying to use server side code based on java NIO(non blocking) from 'The Rox Java NIO Tutorial'. There are lot of incoming socket connections and I would like to accept only 100. So if there are 100 active connections then new ones should be rejected/refused. But how to do that? There is only method ServerSocketChannel.accept() which returns SocketChannel object. Using that object I can call socketChannel.socket().close(), but connection is already open. Here is part of the code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Wait for an event one of the registered channels
            this.selector.select();

            // Iterate over the set of keys for which events are available
            Iterator selectedKeys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) selectedKeys.next();
                selectedKeys.remove();

                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Check what event is available and deal with it
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    this.accept(key);
                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    this.read(key);
                } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    this.write(key);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Reading data", e);
        }
    }
}
```

and accept() mehod:

```
 private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    // For an accept to be pending the channel must be a server socket channel.
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();

    // Accept the connection and make it non-blocking        
    if (noOfConnections < MAX_CONNECTIONS) {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
        Socket socket = socketChannel.socket();
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        // Register the new SocketChannel with our Selector, indicating
        // we'd like to be notified when there's data waiting to be read
        socketChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);//listener for incoming data: READ from client, WRITE to client
        noOfConnections++;
        logger.info("Accepted: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
    } else {

        // REJECT INCOMING CONNECTION, but how?

        logger.warn("Server is full: " + noOfConnections + " / " + MAX_CONNECTIONS);
    }
}
```

If connection is not accepted then accept() method is being called over and over.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why? Why not just let the TCP backlog queue work the way it was designed?

Comment: The backlog is the list of incoming connections, which are pending and not yet accepted. You can't use the backlog to limit the number of actually accepted (connected) sockets.

Comment: @jambjo You are mistaken. Everything on the backlog queue is an already-complete connection(SYN-SYN/ACK-ACK), that simply hasn't been returned by accept() yet.

Comment: @EJP Just to clear it up: Even an `accept`ed connection stays in that queue until it is closed, correct? http://books.google.de/books?id=hHmV57A753MC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=TCP+backlog+queue+java&source=bl&ots=k1w1UqV0yU&sig=cpsFpCd7z2I86UU4QAcYUZMAH2Q&hl=de&sa=X&ei=AeYHUdytPJCL4gTshYHwBw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=TCP%20backlog%20queue%20java&f=false This text sais no: accepted `Socket`s will be removed. So it is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @EJP: Did I write anything else? The backlog is the list of connections, which are not yet accepted by the application. The question was how to reject new connection attempts, when the number of *accepted* connections has reached a limit.

Comment: @jambjo And my comment was why? And why not let the backlog queue work as designed? I don't see the relevance of any of this to my comment.

Comment: @Fidor No, a socket is removed from the queue when accepted()-ed. I wrote that book, and it most certainly doesn't say anything to the contrary. I'm aware of what the OP is asking for. I'm asking *why,* and what is wrong with just letting the backlog queue do its work. I haven't suggested that it's the same thing.

Comment: One work around would be to set some timeout on client side, if connection won't be establish in few seconds, then just close socket so accept() method wouldn't be called anymore. I've tried to first accept connection on server and then close it right away but then client get notification about established connection so not so nice way to handle it.

Comment: @Maciej No. Read the comments above. The connection *is* established and put in the backlog queue, by TCP, even if accept() *never* gets called. You still haven't told us *why* you want to do this at all.

Comment: Ok, I want to limit number of accepted connections to increase performance.I'm trying to write online game where data is exchange between two mobiles. Current server side solutions uses only two threads, one for handling connections and second to do actual work(mainly read data from one mobile client and pass to another one). I don't think it will work fine if there will be hundreds of connections...

Comment: @EJP I see now. Also see my comment to your answer.

Comment: @Maceij So just close the listening socket when you get to the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish that, but I doubt that that's what you really want, or at least what you really should do.

If you want to stop accepting connections, change the interestOps in the server socket channel's selection key to zero, and change it back to `OP_ACCEPT` when you are ready to accept again. In the interim, `isAcceptable()` will never be true, so the problem you describe won't occur.

However that won't cause further connections to be refused: it will just leave them on the backlog queue where in my opinion and that of the designers of TCP they belong. There will be another failure behaviour if the backlog queue fills up: its effect in the client is system-dependent: connection refusals and/or timeouts.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I've changed the code and it seems to work:
`private void accept(SelectionKey key){
...
if (noOfConnections >= MAX_CONNECTIONS) {
 key.interestOps(0);
}}`
After number of connections reach limit accept method is not called anymore. But there is some issue on the client side: I'm calling method `socketChannel.finishConnect()` if selectionKey.isConnectable()`
but it return true even that connection hasn't been accepted on server. It happens for around first 50 connections after listening has been disabled on server side.After that everything is ok, there is ConnectException on client

Comment: @Maciej Read the comments above. Again. There is a listen backlog queue. It contains connections that have already been accepted by the TCP stack even though accept() has not been called yet. That means that finishConnect() will return true for connections in the backlog queue. The fact that this happens 50 times indicates that the backlog queue is 50 elements in size. There is nothing you can do about it. That's what my answer is about. You cannot get the functionality you describe. I said so in my first sentence above.

Comment: How about this: If the accepted Connections reach a max, he redirects to another handler, that does nothing but accept and close incoming connections, may be sends a "Sorry, I'm full. Try again later" before closing. Not exactly what the OP wanted but the Client would know instantly that the Server is congested.

Comment: I've tried that but the thing is that first 'socketChannel.finishConnect()' returns true on client side and I show message "Connected". And just after that there is message "Sorry, I'm full" so it might be quite confusing for an user. Well, when user will press some button like 'Join game' he will see message 'Loading data...' and there won't be any response from the server so I guess then user will know that there is problem with connection.

Comment: @Fidor Why? It doesn't accomplish his objective of *refusing* connections. Why not just leave them pending?

Answer (score 0):

I think any tuning of a backlog queue hardly ever would be a good solution. But probably, you can just stop listening.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed this problem next way:
Pending-state connections on socket are in kind of "middle_state", that mean you cannot control/reject them.
Backlog socket parameter may be used/ignored/treated in different way by specific VM.
That mean you have to accept particular connection to receive associated object and operate it.

Use one thread to accept connection, pass accepted connection to second thread for processing.
Create some variable for number of active connections.
Now, while number of active connections is less than wished maximum, accept connection, rise the number by 1, and pass to second thread for processing.
Otherwise, accept connection and close that immediately.

Also, in connection process thread, than finished, decrease the number of active connections by 1 to point there is one more free channel available.

EDT: Just made the "stub" for server machanism for Java.Net NIO.
May be adapted for OP needs:

```
package servertest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Servertest extends Thread {
    final int MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS = 3;
    int connectionnumber = 0;


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Servertest().start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(33000, 50, InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress());
          while (sc.isBound()) {
            Socket connection = sc.accept();
            if(connectionnumber<=MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS){
                new ClientConnection(connection).start();
                connectionnumber++;
            } else {
                //Optionally write some error response to client
                connection.close();
            }
          }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servertest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private class ClientConnection extends Thread{
        private Socket connection;
        public ClientConnection(Socket connection) {
            this.connection=connection;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //make user interaction

                connection.close();


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servertest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            connectionnumber--;

        }


    }

}
```